# Apply scope in beforeFind hook

Tags: sequelize.js

In hook 'BeforeFind', I'm trying to apply a scope based on the value of a property in the options of the find query.

If the value is not set in the options, the default scope should be used.

I could not make it work. Is that possible and if so, how?

When using the query below, this should use the defaultScope:

```
testModel.findByPk(1)
```

When using the query below, this should use scope 'filtered':

```
testModel.findByPk(1, {filter: 'theValue'})
```

The user scope 'filtered' is set as below

```
function (value) {  
  if(value)
    return {
       include: {otherModel},
       where: {field: value}
    }

  return {
    include: {otherModel},
  }
}
```

In the hook function, I've tried

```
this.scope({method: ['filtered',options.filter]});
```

or

```
this.scope = this.scope({method: ['filtered',options.filter]});
```

I'm using Sequelize 5.8.5 with NodeJS and a mysql DB.